# count number of childs in div with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="post-content">
    <p>xxxxx</p>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
    <p>Test1</p>
    <p>Test2</p>
    <p>Test3</p>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.post-content').each(function () {
        //alert($(this).children.length);
        alert($(this).length);
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7cXKr/

The lenght should be the number of p childs of post-content. why the ouput is not correct?

In this case 1 and 3

Comment: within `$.each`, `this` is instance of selector element...will only have lenght of `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children` is method, you have to call it:

```
alert($(this).children().length);
//    call the method ^^
```

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cXKr/1/)

---

`$(this).length` will always return `1` because since `this` is a DOM element, `$(this)` creates a selection with one element.

Answer (score 0):

Try [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gve7e/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.post-content').each(function () {
        var count = $(this).children().length;
        alert(count);
    });
});
```

---

for finding only children `p` length

```
var count = $(this).children('p').length;
```

---

If you want to include grandchildren too use `.find()`

---

Problem with your code

```
alert($(this).length);
```

refers to  DOM element so length will always be `1`

use `$(this).children().length`

Answer (score 0):

Because the context (this) is a jQuery object, instead of

```
$(this).length
```

You can use

```
$(this).children().length
```

Comment: `this` is a DOM element. `$(this)` is a jQuery object. But `$(this).children()` returns a jQuery object as well, so I don't understand the argument *"Because the context (this) is a jQuery object"*

Comment: You're correct - I should have been clearer. Just trying to show that children needs to be called as a method - I see you explained it better below.